# How to query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have User Model. In user Model I have three user type Admin,Trainer,Student.
I have Job Model, I am storing the the id of trainer ,student and job in pivot table such that one trainer is assigned against one job and many students. Now after storing the ids as foreign key in pivot table.

Now how i can show in a view all trainer, job and assigned students. In la-ravel 5.2

User Model

```
 public function Job_User()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\HTTP\Models\Job', 'jobs_users', 'user_id', 'job_id')->with-pivot('job_id');}

 public function Trainer_User()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\HTTP\Models\Job', 'jobs_users', 'user_id', 'trainer_id')->with-pivot('trainer_id');

    }
```

Comment: `belongs To Many` or `belongsToMany`? `with-pivot` or `withPivot`?

Comment: belongstoMany and wihtPivot